# Symbol meaning - C source file symbol with a slash across it

Tags: c

Does anyone know what the below symbol means?

[image]

I believe it is a reference to the source file not being implemented anywhere, but I'm not sure.

I've looked through the properties to find an explanation but without success. I use ADI's CCES which is based on Eclipse.

Comment: Could it be a broken symlink?  That is,  the file is a symlink but the file it links to doesn't exist?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think so. The source file is in the correct directory, but as I mentioned it is not included in any other files. Then you'd might ask, "Why is it there then?". Legacy, I suppose :)

Comment: It could be a source file that exists but is not used by any of the build rules.  I've no idea; this is pure guesswork.  And “legacy” could be a reason for its existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means: "excluded from the build".

This file will not be compiled and linked in the current build configuration.

From the project explorer right click on this file and select properties:
[image]

Then you can see if it is excluded:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for holding my hand and showing me the way! :)